# Javascript String.Replace doesnt work?

Tags: javascript, replace, split

I'm currently trying to create a navigation system for a website I'm creating. I spent hours trying to figure this out, but i dont understand why its not working
I'm trying to replace all occurrences of "index.html" with the variable filenames.

```
function changeSideNav(filenames)
{   
    var urlarray = window.location.href.split("?");
    var url = urlarray[0];
    alert(url); // This returns "http://localhost/xxx/index.html"
    var urlspl = url.replace(/index.html/gi,filenames);
    alert(url.replace(/index.html/i,filenames) +'/'+ filenames); //This returns "http://localhost/xxx/index.html/newpage.html" (if pram was newpage.html).
    //i txpected it to return "http://localhost/xxx//newpage.html"
    //set a new source
    document.getElementById('SideNavIframe').src = urlspl +'/'+ filenames;
}
```

Edit:
i find this to be strange:
if i try to replace "/index.html" instead of "index.html", it removes the "/" from the output so i get "http://localhost/xxxindex.html/newpage.html".

Comment: Why not simply `url.replace("/index.html", filenames)`?

Comment: That code does in fact work just fine.

Comment: If I were you, I'd throw in an `alert(filenames)` to be sure you know everything that's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this was your prob. But I was stuck on this for a good hour.

Here it is:
`str.replace("s1", "s2")` does NOT do anything to the str.

You need to do:
`str=str.replace("s1", "s2");`

Notice the LHS to explicitly capture the result of the replacement.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You're specifying a string as a regex.  Try specifying a substring as the 1st param to replace(), like so:

```
var url = "http://localhost/xxx/index.html";
url.replace('index.html','changed.html');  // add 'gi' as 3rd param for all occurrences
```

[See docs for String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/regexp_special_characters.html:

> The decimal point matches any single
>   character except the new line
>   character. So, for instance, with the
>   string "The cat eats moths" the
>   regular expression /.t/gi would match
>   the letters 'at' in 'cat', 'at' in
>   'eats' and 'ot' in 'moths', but not
>   the initial 'T' of 'The'.

So you have to escape the period:

```
url.replace(/index\.html/gi,filenames)
```

Comment: But the "." will in fact match the "." in "index.html" just fine.

Comment: @Pointy, yes... if you escape it.

Comment: It will also match a "." if you **don't** escape it, because "." matches any character - including ".".